# resubmit ios app after rejection

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an iOS application that use an Web Server to grab Sports information. Now this application was rejected by Apple, because it shows information about NBA and INTERNATIONAL OLYMPIC COMMITTEE and the english premier league. So I made changes in code to avoid grabbing 
this information.
Now my question is: What do I have to do to resubmit it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is compliant to Apples Guidelines, you should head over to [iTunesConnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) and again click the "Ready to Submit Binary" button. If this is done you need to Archive, which should open the Organizer inside Xcode. Now you should "Validate" and finally "Distribute" your build to the AppStore.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. It gets added to the end of the reviewing queue.

Comment: Sometimes you go to the end of the queue, and sometimes things proceed immediately. I have not been able to discern a pattern.